# What happened to Joffrey's sword, the Widow's Wail?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The question is what it says on the tin: what happened to Joffrey's sword, "Widow's Wail",

> after his death?

Was it passed on to Tommen? If it was, then is there any mention of it in the books, because I can’t remember any. The article in ASOIAF wiki says

> it was passed on to Tommen

but in the chapter referenced there is nothing mentioned of that sorts.

As per the TV show, I clearly saw it placed on

> his dead body in the Great Sept of Baelor

So if there is no clear mention in the books, does it imply the sword was buried with Joffrey's remains?

Comment: Valyrian steel is too rare to be put in a grave they stay in the family for generations, they are priceless. The sword of Eddard Stark was part of the negotiation when Rob startted the war in the north. It is said in the book that Tywin tried to acquire one for years for his family. That's why he didn't restitute Ice to forge Joffrey's sword and the one that Jaime gave to Brienne.

Comment: I recommend you reconsider your accepted answer, as the new answer has clearly provided the exact answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Where is the Sword?

#### Show

Last time the Sword was seen was in Season 4 Episode 3 titled "Breaker of Chains" as you observed yourself.

> In it the sword was laid with Joffrey's corpse on his funeral.

There is no mention of sword's whereabouts afterwards however it is implied that the sword must have passed to Tommen as heir of Joffrey since there is no event which indicates that the sword was misplaced or lost.

> As Tommen is dead as well, We can't say who has the sword now. Perhaps
>  Cersei does, As Tommen's successor.

#### Books

[AWOIAF wiki (Semi Canon)](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Widow%27s_Wail#cite_note-Rasos59.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-1) is correct when it says:

> Upon Joffrey's death, it passes to his younger brother, Tommen
>  Baratheon.

But they have cited the wrong page. They should have instead linked to the Citadel post that I have linked below. It appears to be a human error, I also initially fell for their reference but reading the chapter, it turned out the chapter was before Joffrey's demise.

To answer your question, no there is no mention in books either. It is understandable as Tommen is a child and giving him a razor sharp blade will be folly.

George R.R. Martin has confirmed that Tommen inherited the sword. See [this citadel post](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/FAQ/Entry/1987) for reference.

> **Widow's Wail** - Newly forged out of the melted-down Ice of House Stark,
> Widow's Wail was intended for King Joffrey Baratheon. Following his
> death, **it now belongs to his brother, King Tommen**. It is a longsword.

---

## Can a sword be buried with the bearer?

It can be. In *Dunk and Egg: The Hedge Knight*, Ser Duncan the Tall briefly contemplates against burying sword of his Master Ser Arlan of Pennytree with him, which implies that normal swords can be buried with their bearers.

> “I’d leave your sword, but it would rust in the ground,” he said at
> last, apologetic. “The gods will give you a new one, I guess. I wish
> you didn’t die, ser.”

However special swords which are made of Valyrian steel aren't buried with their bearers. It is evident, by the fact, Valyrian Steel swords are inherited from Father to Son spanning over centuries e.g. Heartsbane, Long Claw, Blackfyre etc.

So it is unlikely that Widow's Wail was buried with Joffrey since none of the other Valyrian steel swords were buried with their bearers.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure about in the books, but in the show, the whereabouts of the sword were unknown from Joffrey's death through the beginning of season 7. In season 7 episode 3, Jaime is talking with Lady Olenna. She says to him:

> No more learning from my mistakes, eh? How will you do it? With that sword? That was Joffrey's sword, wasn't it? Not that he ever used it. What did he call it?
> <sub>**S07E03**</sub>

Jaime replies that it is indeed Widow's Wail. So yeah, Jaime has it.

You can watch the scene here:

Comment: Looks like a good answer I think.

Answer (score 7):

## It passed to Tommen and then to Jaime

The last we see of the sword is indeed on Joffery's corpse in the Great Sept of Baelor.

[image: Joffery's corpse with Widow's Wail]

It's unlikely that he was buried with the sword as weapons with as such value as Valyrian Steel swords are passed down through generations, for example Ice and Heartsbane.

As far as we see in the show the sword is never shown with Tommen, in fact I haven't found a single image of Tommen with a sword at all. The [wikia page on the sword](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Widow%27s_Wail) has this to say:

> While naturally, Widow's Wail would have been **passed down to Tommen Baratheon**, by choice or advice, **he never took up the weapon**. Unseen after Joffrey's funeral, it was assumed to reside somewhere within the Red Keep, possibly tainted in the eyes of potential inheritors as consequence of the cruelty of Joffrey during his reign, though the blade itself was not wielded during any of the atrocities committed.

I'm inclined to agree with this considering the type of ruler Tommen was trying to be. He wanted to be a ruler for the people, joining with religion to be an unstoppable force.

> HIGH SPARROW: Queen Margaery has already atoned for her sins by bringing another into the true light of the Seven.
>   *The doors to the Great Sept of Baelor open. TOMMEN emerges, accompanied by the Kingsguard. The crowd murmurs. JAIME looks back at OLENNA, who looks down. TOMMEN and the Kingsguard walk down the steps until TOMMEN stands beside MARGAERY. TOMMEN takes MARGAERY’s hand.*
>   HIGH SPARROW: Together we announce a new age of harmony. A holy alliance between the Crown and the Faith.
>   *The crowd cheers.*
>   WOMAN: Long live King Tommen and bless you, Queen Margaery!
>   *TOMMEN looks at JAIME. JAIME shakes his head. TOMMEN looks at the crowd.*
>   TOMMEN: **The crown and the faith are the twin pillars upon which the world rests. Together we will restore the Seven Kingdoms to glory.**
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 6, "Blood of My Blood"</sub>

We also have word of God in that GRRM has stated the Widow's Wail did indeed pass to Tommen upon Joffery's death.

> **[Where is the sword Widow's Wail?]**
>   Still at the Red Keep, until such time as King Tommen is old enough to wield it.
>   <sub>[The Citadel](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Loras_Robert_Arryn_the_Clegane_Sister_and_a_Sword)</sub>

During the scene above it looks like Jaime also does not have the sword. Compare the hilts and pommels on each of the swords, note that Widow's Wail is jewelled:

[image: Joffery with Widow's Wail] [image: Jaime confronts the High Sparrow]

The next mention of the sword is when Jaime confronts Olenna:

> OLENNA: If he was so clever why didn't he take Highgarden the moment your gold mines ran dry? I suppose I'll be able to ask him myself soon enough. No more learning from my mistakes, eh? How will you do it? With that sword?
>   *JAIME shakes his head no.*
>   OLENNA: That was **Joffrey's sword**, wasn't it? Not that he ever used it. What did he call it?
>   JAIME: **Widow's Wail**.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 3, "The Queen's Justice"</sub>

Note he only says the name of the sword is Widow's Wail, looking at the sword it doesn't look to be exactly the same, though it could have undergone some slight modifications for Jaime. It looks similar but the jewels at the pommel seem to be missing.

[image: Jaime with Widow's Wail]

So from the quote it implies Jaime is actually now in possession of Widow's Wail but it never explicitly states it.